# UDP Client uses too much memory when sending multiple small parts of a huge array

Tags: c#, visual-studio, networking, udp, client

I'm capturing the desktop with Desktop Duplication API, encoding it in h265 and sending it in parts via UDP (Can't use TCP because I need as low of a latency as possible). I'm doing all of this in C# and Visual Studio, and the memory usage goes through the roof as soon as I uncomment the udpclient.Send().

With it commented everything works great (including the frames capture, the splitting, etc..), as soon as I send it, I reach the 2gb mark in usage in less than 10 seconds and it just keeps ramping up until it crashes. Also, none of the data is lost as my server receives everything so my packet management seems to be good.

```
int offset = 0;
int packetSize = 200;
for (int i=0; i< clone.Length/packetSize; i++)
{
   int diff = clone.Length - offset;
   if (diff > packetSize)
      Array.ConstrainedCopy(clone, offset, subBuffer, 0, packetSize);
   else
      Array.ConstrainedCopy(clone, offset, subBuffer, 0, diff);
   udpClient.Send( subBuffer, packetSize, "255.255.255.255", 9009);
   offset += packetSize;
}
```

I'm at this stage just experimenting with the splitting and everything, and as stated none of that part creates any issues (I know it could be made better). It's just the udpclient.Send() that makes everything go wrong. Any idea on what could cause this and how I could somehow force some memory management with the send?

Comment: Do you have the program receiving the UDP datagrams running on the same computer, and if so, have you checked which process actually consumes the memory? Not that the receiver program stumbles over the last received datagram (Note that if `diff` for the last datagram is smaller than `packetSize`, then the datagram will contain garbage data from the previous datagram in the array area [diff, packetSize). If that is the case, and the receiver is not robust enough to deal with such a scenario, all kinds of wonderful things could happen depending on how exactly the receiver would go off the rails)

Comment: The receiver is on a different device (phone) that's on the same network. I figured the data will be garbage, there's a lot that needs to be done there, this is just the first iteration making sure I do send and receive some data. Thanks for pointing out the potential diff issue, saved me some time trying to figure it out :)

Comment: "_Also, none of the data is lost as my server receives everything so my packet management seems to be good._" This indicates that your problem is seemingly not just related to what's going on in the for-loop (essentially sending all the stuff succeeded before memory consumption does hit a critical level and your program crashes). What if you reduce your program just to a simple console application, read the data piecemeal (in chunks with a size of `packetSize`) from a file and send the chunks via UDP. The console app should do nothing else than that. Will the problem then still occur? (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) If yes, then there is something up with the UdpClient class/or the underlying infrastructure (network stack/drivers), it would be beneficial knowing what platform you are using (.NET Core/.NET Framework). If no, there is something else in your program that triggers/contributes to the problem and you would need to take a closer look at what your program does beside sending those datagrams...

Comment: The whole reason I'm doing this with udp is to save time on latency, I need real time. I can't be writing into a file then sending it. I'm wondering the same if the Send just makes something else break but I can't see it. Removing the Send makes everything normal, even tried writing into a video file to see if the frames are being captures well and they are. Maybe it's the UdpClient framework that's not made for such a thing and I should look into another one.

Comment: My suggestion was not with regard to production code or a solution. Try narrowing down your problem scenario in an attempt to eliminate possible problem causes and to get a better grasp on the issue. Whether you need realtime in your production code doesn't matter with respect to my comments, because my suggestion was not about production code, but about an attempt at troubleshooting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150875/net-udp-socket-send-increasing-memory-usage may be of interest.

Comment: @elgonzo Oh I see, will try that.

Comment: @mjwills Doesn't seem that the issue was solved there.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error "in the dark",  I managed to solve it by doing my own socket management.
It turns out doing as many "Send" calls as possible is permitted, but the socket doesn't respond well to it, meaning it still tries to send even when it's "clogged", and starts leaking memory if that makes sense. I ended up sending asynchronously and waiting to know that the bytes were really sent before attempting another send. Here's the code for it, works perfectly, no memory leaks, 0 packet loss. I started from the simple socket implementation I've taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/darkguy2008/413a6fea3a5b4e67e5e0d96f750088a9) then added the custom management part.

```
    Boolean isAvailable = true;
    public void Send(byte[] data)
    {
            if (!isAvailable)
                return;
            isAvailable = false;
        _socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, (ar) =>
        {     
            _socket.EndSend(ar);
            isAvailable = true;
        }, state);
    }
```

Comment: "_I ended up sending asynchronously and waiting to know that the bytes were really sent before attempting another send._" That is the source of TCP latency, so you may as well use TCP. Also, TCP has optimizations the you do not have in that it can use windows and wait for acknowledgement, sending multiple segments before needing an acknowledgement.

Comment: By " That is the source of TCP latency" do you mean waiting for an "ack" ? Because I don't do that, I rather wait for the socket to send all the bytes before trying another send. Otherwise the socket is just "busy" and memory gets leaked.